# Equivalence between derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

In the paragraph above eq. (3.23) in [this paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1016/S0550-3213(99)00334-X), it is written that for **any** function $f(\lambda x)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x = (x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3)$ (Minkowsky metric $g_{\mu\nu} = \rm{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$ so that $xy = x^0y^0 - \sum_{i = 1}^3 x^iy^i$), then

$$
x^\mu \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu} = \lambda \frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda}
$$

I'm trying to prove this but I have not been succesful:

$$
x^\mu \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu} =  \lambda x^\mu\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\mu} 
$$

Now if somehow we could prove that RHS derivative is the same regardless you derive respect to $x$ or $\lambda$ then we would have

$$
\lambda x^\mu\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\mu} = \frac{\lambda x^\mu}{x^\mu}\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda} = 4\lambda\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda}
$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution in the last line looks really wrong. You can't handle index summing that way. If you write this using $\sum$ instead of Einstein's notation, you'll see that.

Using chain rule:

1. LHS:
   \begin{equation}
   x^\mu\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial x^\mu}=x^\mu\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\nu}\frac{\partial \lambda x^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}=x^\mu\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\nu}\lambda\delta^\nu_\mu=\lambda x^\mu \frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\mu}
   \end{equation}
2. RHS:
   \begin{equation}
   \lambda\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda}=\lambda\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\mu}\frac{\partial \lambda x^\mu}{\partial \lambda}=\lambda\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\mu}x^\mu=\lambda x^\mu\frac{\partial f(\lambda x)}{\partial \lambda x^\mu}
   \end{equation}
   So LHS=RHS.

Comment: I understood your answer, thank you! But what I don't get is that my factor 4 is wrong by writing explicitly the sum: $\sum_{\mu = 0}^3 (x^\mu/x^\mu) = x^0/x^0 + x^1/x^1 + x^2/x^2 + x^3/x^3 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Ok, let's try to figure it out. Maybe I got you wrong. Did you divide one of the previous lines by $x^\mu$ or did you just transform the last line someway like that: $\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda x^\mu}=\frac{\partial}{x^\mu \partial \lambda }$? Because you can't use RHS if you differentiate by $\lambda x^\mu$ and not by $x^\mu$.

Comment: Yes, I did that transformation naively. But under it, the sum $\sum_\mu x^\mu/x^\mu$ is 4, right? I knew that transformation was tricky and potentially wrong but I was trying to figure out how to do it properly, which is your way